# Google analytics recording simultaneous events at different rates

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-analytics

We are trying to track 2 different metrics at the same point in our code. Events of both types are being recorded, but there is a significant difference in the totals reports. The totals for the first call made are roughly 20% higher. I am hoping someone can tell my why the totals reported for one metric are not the same as the other one, which should be created simultaneously. Here is the relevant code:

in the controller:

```
  if (type === 'yahoo') {
    analyticsService.sync('yahoo', PathYahoo + '/' + YahooKey);
    analyticsService.sync('Launch:' + $rootScope.launchType, 'yahoo');
  };
```

in the analyticsService:

```
popupApp.factory('analyticsService', ['$http', function(
  $http) {

  return {
    sync: function(action, label) {
     _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Sync', action, label]);
    }
  }
}]};
```

We are getting far more 'yahoo' events than 'Launch:' events. If anyone can explain the difference or point me towards a fix I would really appreciate it. I am pretty sure that we are well under the rate limits, and that we have few enough sessions to not invoke sampling. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Only thing I can think of is that you're looking at total events incorrectly summed across items and not taking into account the fact you're looking at events in a single vs multiple categories (first param). Switch them around and confirm you're still seeing that difference? Nothing should be causing it... strange

Comment: We switched them to accumulate the weekend data. Will keep you posted.

Comment: Switching them around resulted in 'Launch:' events outnumbering the 'yahoo' events. The difference is still there, and the first one called is the one reported at a higher rate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know why the previous snippet wasn't working correctly, but I have found a solution. I am now pushing the objects into _gaq from the controller. The .push() function can take multiple arrays. Sending both arrays at once appears to have solved the problem.

new controller code:

```
_gaq.push(
  ['_trackEvent', 'Sync', 'yahoo', PathYahoo + '/' + YahooKey], 
  ['_trackEvent', 'Sync', 'Launch:' + $rootScope.launchType, 'yahoo']
);
```